# IE 11 Pointer Events Override

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11, pointer-events

I am trying to override the pointer-events property for a containing div. It works in everything so far except IE 11. Supposedly, the pointer-events property was added to IE 11. For some reason, it won't override though.

```
.divstyle {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.buttonstyle {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

<div class="divstyle">
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            <input type="button" class="buttonstyle" value="test">
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <!-- A BUNCH OF CONTENT THAT I DON'T WANT TO HAVE POINTER EVENTS -->
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <!-- AND ON AND ON -->
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The entire div doesn't allow pointer events, including the button. I would think since the div doesn't have the events at all, IE is supporting the property pointer-events, but when I explicitly set the child to have the events, it won't allow it for some reason. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Should you be using the touch-action rule (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj583807(v=vs.85).aspx#control_default_touch) instead?

Comment: not sure, this is on a laptop without a touch screen

Comment: I have this issue is well.

Answer (score 8):

I had the opposite problem in IE11, I was setting `pointer-events: none` on a parent element, but a link inside that element was still responding to clicks! As it turned out, a span inside the link had `position: relative`, which made it ignore the parent's pointer-events property.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that finds this - IE11 ignores the pointer-events property on inline items such as  tags. Simply switch the display property to anything else for it to function correctly.

Comment: Change display to inline-block fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my particular issue

Answer (score 5):

I believe this will fix your problem:

https://coderwall.com/p/s8pjpg/reseting-pointer-events-on-ie11

So, for your code:

```
.divstyle {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.buttonstyle {
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

perfectly works using inline block ..
display: inline-block;

even by class name works well

```
a.pa-description {
  pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
display: inline-block;
color: gray;
}
```