# How to disable hyper link for ie11 browser

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

This is my html code

@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Account.Home_Forgot_Password, "ForgotPassword", "Account")

I am using below jquery script for disabling hyper link. It is working fine in other browser but not in ie browser.

```
$('.sso-validation').on('blur', function () {
    var email = $(this).val();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        if (emailReg.test(email)) {
            if ((email.toLowerCase().indexOf(".someorg.com", 1) != -1) || email.toLowerCase().indexOf("@@someorg.com", email.length - "@@someorg.com".length) != -1) {
                $("#forgotPassword").css("pointer-events", "none");
            } else {
                $("#forgotPassword").css("pointer-events", "auto");
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718261/ie-11-pointer-events-override

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink` looks like some scripting language - which one? Also, can you share more details?

Comment: We are using MVC Razor engine.